# Staggered grid layout manager dynamic number of columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How i can make dynamic number of columns in `RecyclerView` using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. I already have working `RecyclerView`. Here is screen what i need to do:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if max columns are two that would be quite simple.For the view that occupy the full width,setFullSpan(true) like in your BindView method of Recyclerview Adapter

```
//rlm is RecyclerView.LayoutManager passed in constructor or setter in adapter 
if (rlm instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    /*
     * to make View to occupy full width of the parent
     */
     layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
}
```

Comment: Dear @Ravi Teja
What is rlm?

Comment: instance of layout manager which you can pass in the constructor of the adapter of have a setter method in adapter

Comment: what if you have 3 cols ?

Comment: @Shine it works for n columns.You can only make on element occupy full width.

Comment: yes, I was wondering if I can set an arbitrary number of columns, not 1, not full row but ie 2 or 3. I think this is possible with GridLayout, but not StaggeredGridLayout. Correct?

Comment: Yes.As of now, StaggeredGridLayoutManager is not as flexible as GridLayoutManager