# Android recycler view grid custom views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I have recycler view with grid layout manager and some views (pink/purple rectangles) and my task is to insert a view, (green one) into this recycler view. I thought about using some sort of decorator, or custom view ? But custom view has to be in a different layout manager then I think

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you use StaggeredGridLayoutManager. In `onBindViewHolder` you can check item type by position if it's wide view you can add:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
```

So that view will take hole space in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) to accomplish this. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218787/staggered-grid-layout-manager-dynamic-number-of-columns#answer-36220342) answer to see the usage.