# Display tag like structure in Staggered Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am working on a tag structure currently and to display that I have used Staggeredgrid layout manager of Recyclerview to get the required result as below image:

[image]

But when I used StaggeredGrid, It is providing result as below:

[image]

My code to display adapter in Recyclerview is as given below:

```
val staggeredGridLayoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
rvTags.layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
rvTags.adapter = AllergyAdapter(tags)
```

On increasing the span count to 3, all the items are contracting.
I want that if "Peanut butter" is big enough then only 1 item should come in 1 row and if "neem, garlic and soy" can fit in 1 row, then it should fit.

Basically, I need a way to dynamic span count according to the content size.

Any help will be appreciated.

The suggested answer is not working because it is counting span count for whole of Recyclerview and Not particular row wise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView GridLayoutManager: how to auto-detect span count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666143/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-detect-span-count)

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218787/staggered-grid-layout-manager-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: You could try a FlexBoxLayout https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can go with the dynamic spinning or what you can do is get the help of libraries.

Please check URL for tags libraries.

[Tags Views](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/197?sort=created)

Here is a most suitable view: [ChipView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6685)

With custom layouts : [ChipView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5263)

And for dynamic column binding, you can use AsymmetricGridView.

URL : [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)

Comment: Chipview not worked properly. I already tried AsymmetricGridView. It is messed up in terms of kotlin adaptation.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I got https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2566 from Android Arsenal and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: mention it in your answer to help others, not everyone is going to read comments

Answer (score 1):

I came across such a requirement and ideally, a [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) should be a good option to try.

Answer (score -3):

layoutManager=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);